# My VGA is not displayed in the section Cycles Render - HIP

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

I've got new update Blender 3.0 and new driver 21.Q4, my VGA AMD RX590 is not displayed in the section *Cycles Render - HIP*.

I removed all Blender files and card drivers then installed it again, but nothing. It can be seen in the screenshots

[image: Blender]
[image: AMD]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You GPU doesn't meet the minimum requirements. Please always consult the manual for up to date [system requirements](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html).

> ### HIP – AMD
>
> HIP is supported on Windows and Linux and requires a AMD graphics card
> with the Vega architecture or newer. Both discrete GPUs and APUs are
> supported.
>
> Supported GPUs include:
>
> - Radeon VII
> - Radeon RX Vega Series
> - Radeon RX 5000 Series
> - Radeon RX 6000 Series
> - Radeon RX 7000 Series
> - Radeon Pro WX 9100
> - Radeon Pro W6000 Series

In the message dialog it states

> Requires discrete AMD GPU with RDNA architecture

On the [Wikipedia page for RX500 series AMD GPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_RX_500_series) you can read on the very first line

> These cards are based on the fourth iteration of the Graphics Core Next architecture

Graphics Core Next architecture is a predecessor of newer RDNA, which was first introduced with the Radeon RX 5000 series of video cards, launched on July 7, 2019.

If your card is older than this date, or has a model number of the series RX500, RX400, RX300, RX200, HD8000, HD700, or earlier it is not supported by the HIP API at the moment of writing (early 2022).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I figured out that it won't be supported in future the same, is it? I'm beginner, sorry for kinda these questions.

Comment: AMD engineers are developing HIP, only they know the roadmap and what hardware will be supported in the future. Considering it is different architecture for older cards I wouldn't count much on it, but that is just my hunch.