# AMD rx580 not supporting Blender 2.93 GPU

Tags: rendering, gpu

I recently Bought the AMD Rx580 graphics card for my blender . But the latest Version of blender didnt support my graphics card since its using HIP.. So i tried to install the older version 2.93 to check whether OpenCL can support my graphics card or not for GPU rendering Cycles...But still it shows " No compatible GPUs is found" as shown in below image .. What should i do now.. Someone help me please

[image]

Comment: As mentioned in [Blender 2.93's  Cycles GPU requirements documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#amd), your GPU should theoretically function, but you need to install specifically the "Pro" drivers from AMD, which should be [this one](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/radeon-500-series/radeon-rx-500-series/radeon-rx-580) for an RX 580. Try a clean installation of that driver if needed, reboot, and see how it goes. Otherwise, I would suggest trying to report a bug, but I doubt the devs will do anything for an unmaintained version.

Comment: see my answer bellow

Comment: Can You tell me Which specific drivers I should install? I tried Raedon ProRender Version 3.6, but when i try to enable the addon Blender automatically closes or crashes

Comment: ProRender isn't a driver, it's a render engine. Again, see my answer.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245136/my-vga-is-not-displayed-in-the-section-cycles-render-hip

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Blender 2.93's  Cycles GPU requirements documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#amd):

> OpenCL is supported for GPU rendering with AMD graphics cards. Blender supports GPU rendering on graphics cards with GCN generation 2 and above. To make sure your GPU is supported, see the [list of GCN generations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Core_Next#Generations) with the GCN generation and supported graphics cards.
>
> On Windows and Linux, the latest Pro drivers should be installed from the [AMD website](https://www.amd.com/en/support).

Your GPU uses GCN4 ([source](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#Radeon_500_series)), so it should theoretically function. But you need to install specifically the "Pro" drivers from AMD, which for your RX 580 should be there:
[Radeon™ RX 580 Drivers & Support | AMD](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/radeon-500-series/radeon-rx-500-series/radeon-rx-580)

Try a clean installation of that driver if needed: uninstall whatever AMD driver you have, reboot, install the new one, reboot, and only then open Blender to see how it goes.

Otherwise, I would suggest trying to report a bug using Blender's menu *Help* > *Report A Bug*, but I doubt the devs will do anything for an unmaintained version.

Comment: Thank You so much .. I installed the driver . Now what should I do?

Comment: again, see my answer ;)

Comment: Thank You so much I followed the steps and installed driver..but linux doesnt allowing to install it .."permission denied" is displayed .

Comment: BSE is only for questions about Blender (plus I don't know much about Linux). If you need help installing drivers on Linux I suggest you to ask that specific question on [SU], don't forget to mention precisely which Linux distro you are using as answer vary from that.

Comment: Okay Thank you for your time